# How to press am html submit button more than once

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to press am html submit button more than once? For example, if you had a radio buttons, and the user pressed different radio buttons, the execution of the php would be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `Ajax`/`Jquery` to automatically do something when you change the radio button.

In PHP you can check which radio button you selected by doing a `POST` check.

For example you have this `HTML`:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
```

In your `PHP` you can check which one is selected using:

```
<?php $_POST['gender'] ?>
```

^That will return the value of the radio button thats selected.